# Parse error when trying to install app on Asus eee PC 701 running Android 2.0

Tags: android, parsing

A beta tester of mine has a Asus eee pc 701 running Android 2.0 and he is trying to install an app on it from my web site.  He is able to download the app but is getting a "Parse Error: There is a problem parsing the package" error.  I don't really know if this problem is with the eee pc or with the apk since he is the first person to try to install it.  I built it for 2.0, the manifest has 5 as the minimum API level and I used Eclipse to export and sign it.  But this is my first Android app and he is the first to try to install it, so I am not sure what the problem might be?  Could just be the Android implementation too.  Here is a site about putting Android on the Asus: http://www.liliputing.com/2009/01/how-to-built-google-android-for-the-asus-eee-pc-701.html

Any thoughts on what I might try to get this app installed on his machine?

Comment: Why don't you try it on a normal device first, then worry about the Eee?

Comment: @CommonsWare - I came across the same problem. I am unable to install my app on a 3.2 EMULATOR. Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946460/unable-to-install-app-on-honeycomb-3-2-it-gives-install-parse-failed-not-apk-e

Answer (score 0):

The website you mention is old. I suggest http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode.