# Unable to install app on HoneyComb 3.2 - It  gives INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK error

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-install-apk

Thanks for reading!

A user recently reported that he is not able to install my app on his Asus Eee Pad Transformer (I assume it's got the 3.2 update).

So, I tried with installing the app on a 3.2 emulator and this is my console output:

```
[2011-08-04 14:04:06 - ] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-08-04 14:04:06 - ] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-08-04 14:05:04 - ] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-08-04 14:05:04 - ] Uploading testapp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-08-04 14:05:04 - ] Installing testapp.apk...
[2011-08-04 14:05:34 - ] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK
[2011-08-04 14:05:34 - ] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-08-04 14:05:34 - ] Launch canceled!
```

Can someone please help me out of this? :(

Comment: could you please post the logcat output? that might make helping here easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, basically I figured I already had a earlier version of the  same app installed and with a different signature. I found more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android-a)