# Installing .apk file issue

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I just finished programming an android app. It's target version is 2.3.3, and I installed it on gingerbread, ice cream sandwich and jelly beans and works really fine. But when I tried installing it on a honeycomb cellphone, at the moment of installing the app it pops up an error telling me that theres some error parsing the app, What could have happened? The process I used is connecting the phone to my computer, and copying the .apk file into download folder. From the phone i open the folder and try to install it. I'm I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946460/unable-to-install-app-on-honeycomb-3-2-it-gives-install-parse-failed-not-apk?lq=1). Could be your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you did not sign your app I think. To run the app , we have to sign our app . You can see these links:

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

[How to sign an android apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)